# Preview Images from mysql database of particular product Id only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I've created a script in which every data fetched from mysql database has maximum 4 Image's name and path. Problem is to view those Images user must click on preview link which shows a `<div id='previewdivofimage'>` as per the product Id link clicked and blur rest background. That div

should fetch name and path of the images from mysql database and display in that div but when I click on preview link it just display the last added product images and not the particular id linked which was clicked because to fetch mysql data of that particular product I need to go back and call php functions via jquery or ajax. I am not able to understand how can I fetch the product id and its image's name & path of that particular product Id from that div now, because page should not reload again for doing this activity. Since I am not familiar with Ajax have no clue how does it work. This is **[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/wx84vxnb/)**

Jquery script for making div appear

```
<script>
myBlurFunction = function(state) {
    var containerElement = document.getElementById('".$row['product_id']."');
    var overlayEle = document.getElementById('previewdivofimage');

    if (state) {
    overlayEle.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
    overlayEle.style.display = 'none';
    containerElement.setAttribute('class', null);
    }
};
</script>
```

CSS Code

```
#previewdivofimage
{
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    z-index: 999;
}
#popup
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 630px;
    height: 430px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    border: none;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}
#popupwindow
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    border: none;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}
#closeblury
{
    border:2px solid transparent;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:right;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:black;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #4d4d4d;
}
#nothing
{
    border:1px solid transparent;
    margin-left:15px;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}
#showcaseboxcontainer
{
    height:91%;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#productimg
{
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-left:5px;
    width:150px;
}
#fimg
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Link code

```
<a style='cursor:pointer;' onClick='myBlurFunction(1);myFunction(".$row['product_id'].")' id='".$row['product_id']."'>
    Preview
</a>
```

Div Code

```
<div id='previewdivofimage'>
    <div id='popup'>
        <div id='popupwindow'>
            <div id='closeblury' onclick='javascript:myBlurFunction(0);'>
                X
            </div>
            <div id='nothing'>
            </div>
            <div id='showcaseboxcontainer'>
                <div id='productimg'>
                    <img id='fimg' src='".$row['product_image_name_first']."'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get this error in the fiddle. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null -- For clearing a class, you could try `containerElement.className='';`

Comment: @AndrewR I tried viewing Fiddle, I am not getting any such error. I don't understand why are you getting it